# Why is console.log logging twice inside contructor and render method?

Tags: reactjs

Why is console.log logging twice inside contructor and render method ?

[image]

Comment: Can you show code where you define routes or where you render App.js to html ?

Comment: Read more how react lifecycle works. This diagram maybe helpful: https://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/

Comment: actually it's simple CRA without routes

Comment: @YudiKrisnandi Se my ans then

Comment: StrictMode checks for unsafe lifecycle and legacy/deprecated API usage. If you don't want to use this feature then Inside your index.js you can completely remove this wrapper and use only <App />. Provided answer by @RajanLagah will work and stop extra render.

Answer (score 3):

In simple CRA they do

```
<React.StrictMode>
   <div>
     <App />
   </div>
</React.StrictMode>
```

**React.StrictMode**

Is for developers help. It will show helpful warning and all. For that it need to intentionally double-invoking the following functions:

1. Class component constructor, render, and shouldComponentUpdate
   methods
2. Class component static getDerivedStateFromProps method
3. Function component bodies
4. State updater functions (the first argument to setState)
5. Functions passed to useState, useMemo, or useReducer

You can remove **React.StrictMode** by **<>**

And you can learn more about strict mode from [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html)